# What's the significance of /dev/null in a git show commit?

Tags: git

What does the `--- /dev/null` signify in by `git show commit` output?

This is an addition of a new file, so I assume it's saying that nothing was removed, but why the reference to `/dev/null`?

```
$ git show a395a
commit a395a7bb4abcc606022ac14a07794b2d3c18bd5b
Author: David Banks <BanksySan@googlemail.com>
Date:   Sun Apr 12 17:41:08 2015 +0100

    My first commit.

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e965047
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Hello
```

Comment: Specifying `/dev/null`, as opposed to nothing, allows uniformity with the structure/paths.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means that because test.txt is a new file, in the diff shown, it was compared to "nothing"; the "file" /dev/null.

Comment: OK, go it really does a full diff on a new file, it just diffs it against `/dev/null`.  Cool, thanks.

Comment: To be complete, we must add that "/dev/null" is a "real" file in the Unix filetree. It is used using `|` in the command line and shell to throw away a content generated that we don't need anymore...

Answer (score 12):

You can find that convention (diff against "no file") from the very beginning of Git itself.

The goal was to be more like the [**`cg-patch`**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cg-patch) Linux tool, which apply a patch from a file, input, or a commit.

See [commit 2f97813](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f97813870c73a89b673ea7882f2a078d25c2dcd), Git 0.99, Apr. 2005:

> ### Make `diff-cache` and friends output more `cg-patch` friendly.
>
> This changes the way the default arguments to diff are built when
>   diff-cache and friends are invoked with `-p` and there is no
>   `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable.
>   It attempts to be more `cg-patch` friendly by:
>
> - **Showing diffs against `/dev/null` to denote added or removed files**;
> - Showing file modes for existing files as a comment after the diff label.